# Can't update second row of the database

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

I have made a program to edit the database taking input from the entries of tkinter GUI. I am successful in updating the first row with my code given below but I haven't any idea how to go to the second row for updating.

And the reason i have used `range((len(names)-1)` is that I don't want to update ID.

Code:

```
from sqlite3 import*
conn = connect('library.db')

names = ['ID', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'BOOK', 'RETURN']
data = [(2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'),(2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE') ]

for i in range((len(names)-1)):

    print("UPDATE LIBRARY set "+ names[1+i] +"= ? where " + names[0] +" = ?", (str(data[0][1+i]),str(data[0][0])))

    conn.execute("UPDATE LIBRARY set "+ names[1+i] +"= ? where " + names[0] +" = ?", (str(data[0][1+i]),str(data[0][0])))
    conn.commit()
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider multiple column updates in same query with separated assignments in `SET` clause. Also, build prepared SQL statement first, then call `executemany` but move ID to the end to align positionally with parameters:

```
names = ['ID', 'NAME', 'CLASS', 'BOOK', 'RETURN']    
sql = "UPDATE [LIBRARY] SET {0}{1} WHERE {2} = ?".format(" = ?, ".join(names), " = ?", names[0])

print(sql)
# UPDATE [LIBRARY] SET ID = ?, NAME = ?, CLASS = ?, BOOK = ?, RETURN = ? WHERE ID = ?

initial = [2211, 2213]
nested_initial = [(i,) for i in initial]

data = [(2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE'), (2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE')]
data = [[d[0]]+list(d)[1:]+list(i) for d,i in zip(data, nested_initial)]
print(data)

# [[2217, 'ARJ', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2211], [2216, 'JOHN', '10A', 'NONE', 'NONE', 2213]]

conn.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Simply remove `[1:]` wherever it appears as this subsets out first item being `ID` from list.

Comment: I want these two values `initial = [2211, 2213]` in the place of d[0]. I tried `data = [list(d)+[initial[d]] for d in data]` but gave me an error

Comment: See updated answer using `zip` in list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need an inner loop to iterate through `data`.

```
for i in range((len(names)-1)):
  for d in data:
    conn.execute("UPDATE LIBRARY set "+ names[1+i] +"= ? where " + names[0] +" = ?", (str(d[1+i]),str(d[0])))
conn.commit
```

But this is complex and needs a separate update for each field.

Many problems can be made simpler by restructuring the data. It would be easier, faster, and less error prone to use a dict of dicts keyed by the ID.

```
updates = {
  2217: { 'NAME': 'ARJ', 'CLASS': '10A', 'BOOK': 'NONE', 'RETURN': 'NONE' },
  2216: { 'NAME': 'JOHN', 'CLASS': '10A', 'BOOK': 'NONE', 'RETURN': 'NONE' }
}

for id, update in updates.items():
    # update library set ID = ?, NAME = ?, ... where id = ?
    sql = "update library set "
    sql += ", ".join("{} = ?".format(key) for key in update)
    sql += " where id = ?"

    conn.execute(sql, (update.values(), id))

# Unless you have need to commit immediately, for efficiency,
# commit once all the updates are complete.
conn.commit
```